# SMTP and POP3 Restriction

Tags: email, smtp, pop3

My Network administrators decided to disable SMTP and POP3 ? I can't use Outlook, Apple Mail or Thunderbird ? is there a way to get around this ?

Comment: use a tunnel with putty over port 443 to a ssh server outside for example at your home...

Comment: use web clients, I guess

Answer (score 2):

If they have disabled it, its most likely for a reason. So you probably will get no help here from the folks who put those policies in place.

Comment: Right. From the FAQ, this site is for system admins. You're not one, you're trying to get around the folks who admin your company's systems. Talking with management and/or the sysadmin team about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOCKS or HTTP proxy.